# nhibernate upgrade

Tags: nhibernate, upgrade

there is a project using nhibernate v2.1 and i have been wondering whether v3 is backwards comatible with 2.1?

I mean if i drop v2.1 dll and replace it with v3 dll would all code work?

thnx for your opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just made the move recently. There were no "out of the way" breaking changes unlike when having to upgrade from 1.2 to 2.0. In fact we didnt have to change anything in our code when we upgraded from 2.1.2 GA to 3.0

However there are some breaking changes that can be seen in the release notes that accompany the downloads.

In relation to the question you asked with the NHibernate dll:

NHibernate depends on log4net, Castle, Iesi.Collections etc so when you upgrade ensure that these dlls are correct also - We cater for this easily by positioning downlaoded NHibernate binaries in a "lib" repository and all projects that need NHibernate reference the NHibernate.dll in the NHibernate "lib" folder. This then solves the dependency issue as all other necessary NHibernate dependencies are in situ already in the same folder as the NHibernate.dll by default.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost compatible. If you didn't use linq. Read realease info, there is list of breaking changes.